# Polars iterating through dataframes

Tags: python, for-loop, python-polars

I have 3395 dataframes in polars as dataframes[0],dataframes[1] and so on. I want to get an input value from the user and then if that input matches the the cell value (by using dataframes_list[i].item(0,7)) in any one of the 3395 dataframes I want to assign it to a new df and use it to do further analysis.

Normally with Pandas I would use a for loop. Example:

```
for i range (len(dataframes):
 if user_input== dataframe[i].iloc[0][5]:
    df= dataframes[i]
```

How to do this in polars.

Comment: Surely polars has documentation that covers how to use it? What did the docs tell you, and how did that not work?

Answer (score 1):

You can replicate what you are doing in pandas without much modification.

If you are not using the list index for anything other than retrieving the dataframe, then prefer the below more direct approach rather than `for i in range(len(dataframes))`

```py
for df in dataframes:
    if user_input == df.item(0, 7):
        # do futher analysis
```

All that being said, looping over a list of 3395 dataframes is not very efficient. Is there any way you could do what you need with all the data in a single dataframe?